# Pepper robot factory reset using Chorégraphe

Tags: pepper

I lost the pepper password, and looking for the 'hardest' reset using Choregraphe.
Some answers mentioned using chorégraphe and python codes, but cannot find the full instruction anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've lost the robot's password, you can use this use an Aldebaran account to factory reset the robot.

Open the settings menu on Pepper's tablet and go to the third tab, like below (sorry, it's for a NAO, but looks similar for Pepper). Click Edit account to check your account details. If you can't remember the password you can create a new account [here](https://cloud.aldebaran.com/) and enter those details.

Then go to the settings tab and click factory reset. Enter your Aldebaran account details and Pepper will begin the reset. After about 10 minutes Pepper will restart and you can enter a new robot password.

Note: this will erase all the applications and data saved on your robot. But unfortunately, if you've forgotten the robot password there's no way to recover the data.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use that, but it said ssh server error.

Comment: Do you have any idea with python + Choregraphe method to hard (factory) reset?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the error you're getting? Is Pepper connected to the internet? You won't be able to factory reset through Choregraphe without the robot password.

Comment: I updated it. I connected using LTE hotspot, wifi, another wifi, but always show ssh server error. Sine Choregraphe can detact the robot and get video, I believe somethow it an make it work....

Comment: You edited my post instead of yours haha. But you don't want to be trying to change the robot's password. Can you go to the settings menu like in the picture I posted? Then edit account. Do you remember your aldebaran account details?

Comment: Dominic, Oooops sorry, I am not familiar with edit function. Actually, I prefer change the pass and fully reset the systems. (I am suspicious that the os is also may corrupted, since the first screen is not one as in manual)

Comment: To reset the password, you must factory reset the robot using the method I've described. Then it will let you choose a new password. Go to the fourth tab of the settings like I said, click factory reset, and enter your Aldebaran accounts details. Then Pepper will perform a factory reset and you can set a new password.

Comment: It displays ssh server error. I entered my account detail and any random alphabet, but the results were same.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the ssh server error you get with your Aldebaran account?

Comment: Just updated the screenshot. I believe the second screen should show the 'account edit' menu, but it doesn't. Maybe the OS version is older....

Comment: Because it still has the left and right arrows - that looks like it's still on the setup screen. Are you able to click all the way to the right and exit that screen? Alternatively, can you connect with Choregraphe and manually run the boot config app? Which OS version do you have does it say?

Comment: The strange behavior was happened due to (possibly) previous unsuccessful factory reset or OS upgrade. I accessed using Safari browser and successfully added the new mail accounts and finished factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

try installing robot settings application
[robot settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw0G8.png)

and go to settings, there you can see a section that says change account, just add a new account and reset the robot if you want